# Problemas con arrays en programación C

Tags: array

Me piden que escriba un programa en C en el que:

1. Se genere un **array de entre 5 y 10 números aleatorios comprendidos entre el 1 y el 4**: es decir, que sean, por ejemplo: 4 1 4 3 2 2 1 (array de 7 posiciones).
   He intentado mediante un #define max_num 10 y min_num 5 pero también me mantiene el error: "no se permite la llamada a función en una expresión constante".
2. Por otra parte, me piden que un jugador vaya introduciendo los números en la posición i (que también se deberán almacenar en un array con la misma cantidad de números para poder imprimir luego los aciertos y los fallos)

Este código no me lo deja compilar porque no acepta el rand()11+5 del principio, he sustituido el rand por un número int (5, por ejemplo) y compila bien la primera parte del código pero luego imprime posiciones extra, es decir, primero imprime 1, luego 2 y luego repite 2, después pude 3 y repite 3 y así... Estoy desesperada, no sé qué hacer:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define cantidad_numeros (rand() 6 + 5)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i, j;

    int numeros[cantidad_numeros], numero_introducido, numero_acertado = 0;
    float porcentaje_aciertos;
    bool acierto;

    printf("Se han generado %d numeros aleatorios\n", cantidad_numeros);
    printf("Es tu turno jugador. Vas a llenar tu el array.\nRecuerda que has de usar numeros del 1 al 4!\n");

    for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
        numeros[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
        printf("%d\n", numeros[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < cantidad_numeros; j++) {

        while (j <= cantidad_numeros) {
            printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &numero_introducido); 
            if (numero_introducido < 1 || numero_introducido > 4) {
                printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", j + 1);
                scanf("%d", &numero_introducido);
            }

            if (numero_introducido >= 1 && numero_introducido <= 4) {
                if (numero_introducido == numeros[i]) {
                    acierto = true;
                    numero_acertado++;
                    j++;
                    printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", j + 1);
                    scanf("%d", &numero_introducido);
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                    printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", j + 1);
                    scanf("%d", &numero_introducido);
                }
            }
        }

        porcentaje_aciertos = numero_acertado * 100 / cantidad_numeros;
        printf("Has acertado %d numeros de %d\n", numero_acertado, cantidad_numeros);
        printf("Lo que representa un %.2f\n", porcentaje_aciertos);

        for (int l = 0; l < cantidad_numeros; l++) {
            printf("Has acertado los siguientes\n");
            printf("Posicion %i has indicado un %d y habia un %i\n", l + 1, numero_introducido, &numeros[i]);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay manera sencilla de usar funciones como `rand()` en un `#define` debido a las limitaciones del preprocesador, mejor pasa esa lógica a la función main y crea el numero aleatorio allí.

```
int lowerlimit = 5, upperlimit = 10; // limite superior en inferior
    srand(time(0)); // semilla
    int cantidad_numeros = (rand() % (lowerlimit - upperlimit + 1)) + lowerlimit; // obtenemos numero entre 5 y 10 (inclusivo)
```

Después hay algunos pequeños errores aquí y allá, defines un arreglo con el tamaño **N** donde **N** es el numero aleatorio definido anteriormente y lo llenas correctamente con números aleatorios entre 1 y 4.

Después haces un segundo for y vas pidiendo números que el usuario debe 'adivinar' para ver mas tarde si coinciden los números aleatorios, pero no usas un arreglo con los números introducidos por el usuario, sino que usas una variable que vas sobrescribiendo en cada iteración entonces tu programa no podrá recordar los números que introdujo el usuario excepto el ultimo.

Mejor define un arreglo *'numeros_introducidos'* para ir guardando las entradas del usuario:

```
int numeros[cantidad_numeros], numero_introducido, numeros_introducidos[cantidad_numeros], numero_acertado = 0;
    float porcentaje_aciertos;
    bool acierto;

    printf("Se han generado %d numeros aleatorios\n", cantidad_numeros);
    printf("Es tu turno jugador. Vas a llenar tu el array.\nRecuerda que has de usar numeros del 1 al 4!\n");

    for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
        numeros[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
        printf("%d\n", numeros[i]);
    }
    
    j = 0;

   while (j < cantidad_numeros) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &numero_introducido); 
        
        if (numero_introducido < 1 || numero_introducido > 4) {
            printf("Rango incorrecto ");
            continue;
        } else {
            numeros_introducidos[j] = numero_introducido;
            if (numero_introducido == numeros[j]) {
                acierto = true;
                numero_acertado++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
```

En el codigo anterior defino un solo while, si la entrada esta en el rango 1-4 entonces se registra en el arreglo y j se incrementa, si el valor esta fuera del rango lanzo un mensaje de error y j mantiene su valor, usando 'continue' para pasar a la siguiente iteracion.

Finalmente saliendo de ese bucle while, teniendo tanto el arreglo de numeros aleatorios como el arreglo de las entradas de usuario, puedo saber el primer numero aleatorio y la primera entrada del usuario, el segundo aleatorio y la segunda entrada de usuario etc.

Te dejo una demo [aqui](https://onlinegdb.com/cuRUR-6ZfL).

Comment: Wow, muchísimas gracias, efectivamente esto soluciona el problema. Voy a intentar aplicarlo al código (por no copiar y pegar lo que has escrito). Gracias!!!

Comment: @M31 si la respuesta te sirvió márcala como aceptada

Comment: Perdona, que soy nueva en esta web y todavía no sé muy bien cómo funciona, marcada como aceptada! Gracias!

Comment: ¿sabrías indicarme por qué este código no compila en Visual Studio pero sí en Visual Studio Code (esto seguramente es porque Visual Studio no tiene un compilador c/c++ y  por eso no acepta un array con valores aleatorios)? o ¿por qué en Codeblocks me  indica (después de que yo haya cambiado el final del código) qué números son correctos y qué números son incorrectos pero en Visual Studio Code no?

Comment: @M31 te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta, no puedo saber que mensajes de error tienes y los comentarios de preguntas son solo para el problema expuesto en la misma. Haz otra pregunta.